# Problema al enviar parametros en ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Holaa

Estoy haciendo un dashboard el cual tiene que hacer calculos para mostrarlos, yo mando los datos atraves de jquery con ajax. 
El problema es que se tarda mucho en devolver los resultados, tambien me di cuenta que no envía los parametros inmediatamente despues del evento.

El evento es el siguiente:

```
$(function(){
 $('#filter').click(function(){
                    var desde = $('#datepickerInicio').val();  
                    var hasta = $('#datepickerFin').val();               

                     $.ajax({  
                          url:"getDatos.php",  
                          method:"POST",
                          dataType: "json", 
                          data:{desde:desde, hasta:hasta},   
                          success:function(data)  
                          {

                           $('#extmas').text(data[0].extmas);
                           $('#namemas').text(data[0].namemas);
                           $('#timemas').text(data[0].timemas);
                           $('#extmenos').text(data[0].extmenos);
                           $('#namemenos').text(data[0].namemenos);

                          }    
                     });    
           });  
      });
```

Cuando se realiza el evento, en la parte del inspector del explorador veo que no está mandando los parametros.El archivo que hace los calculos es el siguiente

```
include "conexion.php";

$return_arr = array();
/* Si la conexión a la base de datos , ejecuta instrucción SQL. */
if ($mysqli) 
{
    # code...

    if(isset($_POST['desde'], $_POST['hasta']))
    { // Pasará si existe y tiene datos

    /*Seleccionar todos */
        $callanswer=0;
        $callnoanswer=0;
```

En esta parte hace varias consultas

```
 $row_array['answer']=$callanswer;
        $row_array['noanswer']=$callnoanswer;
        $row_array['busy']=$callbusy;

array_push($return_arr,$row_array);  
    }

}
/* Cierra la conexión. */

/* Codifica el resultado del array en JSON. */

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Y devuelve los datos...
He usado esta estructura en otros sitios y ha funcionado. Alguna idea de lo que está provocando eso?

Comment: ¿La petición AJAX retorna estado 200? ¿O un 500?

Comment: Resultó que el problema estaba en la estructura de las consultas